# CS50 Filter(less) blur function

Tags: c, cs50

I'm extremely new to CS and thought I would turn to the community for help. I've been stuck on the blur function of the filter (less) pset for 6+ hours now and have tried so many variations and adaptions, but nothing seems to be pass check50.

I would really appreciate any insights or suggestions (the more detail the better)!

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
     }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            for (int h = - 1; h < 2; h++)
            { 
                float counter = 0.0; 
                int avgGreen = 0;
                int avgRed = 0;
                int avgBlue = 0;
                for (int k = - 1; k < 2; k++)
                {
                    if (i + h < 0 || i + h > height -1)
                    {
                        continue; 
                    }
                    if (j + k < 0 || j + k > width - 1)
                    {
                        continue; 
                    }
                    avgGreen += copy[i + h][j + k].rgbtGreen;
                    avgBlue += copy[i + h][j + k].rgbtBlue;
                    avgRed += copy[i + h][j + k].rgbtRed;
                    counter++;
                }
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(avgred/ counter);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(avgblue/ counter);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(avggreen/ counter);
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are defining and zeroing `avgGreen`, `avgBlue`, and `avgRed` inside your inner `for` loop over `k`. You need to do that outside of that loop, but in the loop over `j`.
2. It's very strange to have a float counter. I would suggest using an int. But note that you still want to cast to float when where you do the division; otherwise the `round` function will have no effect (because the result of the division will always be truncated).
3. At the end, you refer to `avgred`, `avgblue`, and `avggreen`, but those are undefined. (Check the capitalization.)
4. The three lines where you assign the RGB values to `image[i][j]` are inside the for loop over `h`. They need to be outside that loop. They appear at a glance to be outside that loop because they are indented incorrectly. The `}` below those lines needs to be above them.
5. After those changes, your results should be functionally correct, but the processing will be quite slow. If you care about performance, you should avoid comparisons within inner loops. Comparison operations break the CPU's pipeline, which can be very slow. You have up to four compares in your inner loop. It would be better to do those comparisons outside the two inner loops, and instead to find the `hMin`, `hMax`, `iMin`, and `iMax` based on avoidance of running outside the pixel buffer. Then you can loop `h` from `hMin` to `hMax` and loop `i` from `iMin` to `iMax`, for much better speed.

Comment: Thanks so much @howlium! It worked! I really appreciate the help!